# need to retrive information from the drop down when click on submit button

Tags: php

when i select a value from the dropdown and then hit submit how can i retrive the information for what i have selected from the drop down from the database.
Means i have created another colummn in the table so whats been selected in the drop down that information should pop-up  which relates to that from the table

Comment: the title makes sense... I don't understand what's in the body.

Comment: You'll have to access the variable `$_POST['name_of_dropdown']`.
I'm not sure what you mean by adding anything to some table, please clarify.

Comment: You need to read some tutorials on basic PHP and MySQL (I assume this is the DBMS you're using) instead of asking an ambiguous question here expecting a fully written solution.

Answer (score 2):

Can't believe I'm actually writing it , but this is the main idea:

```
<?php

if(array_key_exists('sendForm' , $_POST))
{
 echo $_POST['someName']; //will show the value of the selected option
}
else
{
?>
<form method='post' action=''>
<select name='someName'>
<option value='value1'>Something1</option>
<option value='value2'>Something2</option>
<option value='value3'>Something3</option>
</select>
<br />
<input type='submit' name='sendForm' value='Submit!'>
</form>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: +1 While I believe my answer is more closely reflects what the OP asked, I think that if Ofir's answer is an option, it's the better one! Or, if whatever the OP needs can be accomplished client-side: JavaScript.

Comment: Don't forget to sanitize the input.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming (and there are *quite a few* assumptions to be made with your question) that:

1. You are doing this in pure PHP and an HTML form (no javascript), and
2. That you can already successfully insert the record into the database (since you mention "the table"), and
3. That the table contains an `AUTO_INCREMENT` primary key id column,

You can use PHP's `mysql_insert_id()` function to retrieve the last record inserted into the database from the current connection, like:

`$last_record = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = " . mysql_insert_id());`

Comment: The problem with his question is "php table" , does it mean DB? Does it mean HTML table? Only god knows...oh! and also the OP.

Comment: Yes, quite right! As I said, *many assumptions* :) Mostly drawn from the phrasing "insert into table", but maybe I'm reading too much into it.

Answer (score 0):

```
<label for='formCountries[]'>Select the countries that you have visited:</label><br>
<select multiple="multiple" name="formCountries[]">
    <option value="US">United States</option>
    <option value="UK">United Kingdom</option>
    <option value="France">France</option>
    <option value="Mexico">Mexico</option>
    <option value="Russia">Russia</option>
    <option value="Japan">Japan</option>
</select>
```

The PHP code to process this field is very similar to the checkbox code. $_POST['formCountries'] returns an array of the selected values.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['formSubmit']))
{
  $aCountries = $_POST['formCountries'];
  if(!isset($aCountries))
  {
    echo("<p>You didn't select any countries!</p>\n");
  }
  else
  {
    $nCountries = count($aCountries);
    echo("<p>You selected $nCountries countries: ");
    for($i=0; $i < $nCountries; $i++)
    {
      echo($aCountries[$i] . " ");
    }
    echo("</p>");
  }
}
?>
```